# Generating random numbers between 2 values in 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Recently I've started learning Java and been having plenty of problems. I have tried searching on the website, but I can't seem to get the answer I need. Apologies if there is an answer and the mistake is on my part.

Please take a look at my code first:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Random num = new Random();
        int[][] multi = new int [3][];
        int test = 1;             // comments for stackoverflow questions   
        int test2 = 10;           // how can i create something that will range from 1-9?
        int test3 = test2-test;   // trying this has always generated 0-9 instead

    multi[0] = new int [] {num.nextInt(test3), num.nextInt(test3), num.nextInt(test3)};
    multi[1] = new int [] {num.nextInt(test3), num.nextInt(10), num.nextInt(10)};
    multi[2] = new int [] {test3, test3, num.nextInt(10)};

// PLEASE IGNORE THE 2D ARRAYS, it's just something I am testing on

    int rows = 3;
    int columns = 3;

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<columns; j++) {
            System.out.print(multi[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }   
}
```

I am trying to simulate a jackpot, whereby I want to generate numbers between 1 to 9 in all of the 2D array I have created. However I do not know how to generate the numbers between *1 to 9*, I have creating only ranges *0-10* and *0-9*

My idea is that, once I complete this 2D array of ranges *1-9*, then I could use a certain amount of *if-else* statements to make the user win the jackpot whenever the center row or diagonal rows has 3 of the same numbers.

I have also tried using:

```
int test3 = num.nextInt(test2-test+1)-test;
```

This would generate numbers between *1-9* but if I were to use it all, it will always generate the same numbers to me, otherwise it gives an exception because of negative numbers.

Comment: Consider adding "1" to your random result to change the "lower" boundary.

Comment: @Jägermeister what do you mean?

Comment: @reyareya I think he means generate a random number between 0-8 and then add 1 to that result.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want a random number between inclusive 1 and 9, this should help:

```
Random r = new Random();
int num = r.nextInt(9) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a value from 1-9:

```
Random random = new Random();
int n = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
```

To apply this in your case:

```
multi[0] = new int [] 
   {num.nextInt(9) + 1, num.nextInt(9) + 1, num.nextInt(9) + 1};
```

Comment: ohmygod!!! thanks! as simple as this looks/sounds, this works perfectly. I never thought that using a simple "+1" would work immediately. I thought it was a problem of the integers i was using.....

Comment: Maybe you just thought the `Random.nextInt()` method always returns a  value of at least 1?  ;)   I suggest you read the Java API, it's quite good for learning exactly what you can do with its standard libraries. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random number like this:

```
Math.rand() * i // Generate number between 0 and i-1
```

Or

```
  Math.rand() * i + 1 // Generate number between 1 and i
```

Comment: He is already generating the number it sounds, but it is 0-9, when he wants 1-9.